# strstr returning null, because str_replace isn't good enough

Tags: php, string, null, str-replace, strstr

I'm in this situation.
I need to replace some tags into text ma similar input are forcing me to change my code.

My variabiles are,

- A string $string with tags
- An Array $arr with this fomat { $tag => $values}

Before my code was:

```
$string = str_replace(array_keys($arr), array_values($arr), $string);
```

But in case like that:

```
'alfa' => 1,
'alfa 2' =>3,
```

and $string is `alfa, alfa 2` the output is `1, 1 2` and not `1, 3,`

So I changed with `strstr` function:
`$string = strstr($arr,$string);`
But the returning value of strstr is null and a see this error message

> Warning: strstr() expects parameter 1 to be string

Where I do wrong?

Thanks in advice

Comment: I think the function you want to use is `strtr()`, not `strstr()`.

Comment: Adding to @mad-dog's comment: Compare `strtr — Translate characters or replace substrings` with `strstr — Find the first occurrence of a string` in your favourite PHP documentation ;-)

Comment: Maybe you could try [sorting](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) `$arr` first so that longer `$tag` comes first.

Comment: Thanks @MadDog, ;) 

Now it's working  ^^

Comment: You might also try  sorting your array from longer to shorter tags. This will get the longer matches before the shorter ones.